# Is there a term for the phenomenon of not being able to pass the car in front of you?

Tags: single-word-requests

During my commute to work, I primarily drive on a two lane road in a rural area. Every day, without fail, I get stuck behind someone driving at or below the speed limit and it frustrates me. I would simply pass them, but it seems EVERY time there is a passing zone, there is oncoming traffic preventing me from passing. Is there a term for this phenomenon?

Comment: Stuck in traffic?

Comment: You found it already. You _got stuck behind a car_.

Comment: What I mean is, there won't be ANY cars, then as soon as it's a passing zone there will be a car coming in the opposite direction, preventing me from passing...

Comment: Well, your thought is _selective perception_.

Comment: Perhaps you don't notice so much being behind someone when *not* in a passing zone.  If you did, maybe the perceived phenomenon would disappear.  IOW, perhaps there are plenty of times when there is not a passing zone and there is an oncoming car.  You are perhaps less likely to become aware and annoyed in that case, since you cannot pass legally then anyway.  Just a thought.

Comment: Does it happen even more when you are in a hurry?

Comment: Drew, you are probably right there. And Frank, when I am not in a hurry, I don't try to pass people... :p

Comment: @teratogen: What Drew explained is _selective perception_.

Comment: Great question, TBC to you mean more stuck behind ONE SPECIFIC car (like when you're stuck behind say a tractor), or do you mean stuck behind the "overall flow" of traffic?

Comment: Ahh .. or do you mean that feeling that: "it FELT LIKE every time I had a chance to pass, there was an oncoming car!"

Comment: Law enforcement.

Comment: I don't know if there's a word for it, but your narrative reminded me of the short scene that's 90 seconds into [this _Pink Panther_ video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lJil0m4e5A).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Murphy's driving law](http://murphyslaws.net/by_topic.htm#24)

- As soon as you change lanes to a faster lane, it becomes the slowest lane.
- If you try to change lanes to get off the ramp, the guy in the lane to your right will always speed up.
- On a two lane road, no cars will come from the opposite direction where the lanes are divided by a white line. However, as soon as it's allowed to bypass, the opposite lane is jammed.  [<sub>source</sub>](http://www.murphys-laws.com/murphy/murphy-cars.html)

[Barrett's Laws of Driving:](https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/personal/ibf/some.html)

- The vehicle in front of you is traveling slower than you are.

Answer (score -2):

I would say you got *bogged down* or *squeezed*.  Stuck works too.

> ▸ verb:  get stuck while doing something
>
> ▸ verb:  cause to slow down
>   or get stuck
>
> ▸ verb:  cause to
>   get stuck as if in a mire
>
> ▸ verb:  be unable to move further